# Runtime Error While Initializing Global Variables

Tags: c++, initialization, global-variables, runtime-error

My code simply reads problems from 42 different text files and solves them, and then prints out the solution.

I know it is not a good practice but I am using global variables such as

```
Customer *customers;
vector<int> *schedules;
double **distanceMatrix;
```

and suppose that I have to do this.

My problem appears while initializing `distanceMatrix`:

```
distanceMatrix = new double*[n];
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    distanceMatrix[i] = new double[n];
```

The part that I could not understand is, I get a runtime error not in the first problem, not in the second, but at random problems between 9 and 25.
Hence, I am pretty sure that files are well-formatted.

I do not have any syntax errors.

Sometimes, I get runtime error while reading from text file 9, sometimes 13, sometimes 22 etc.

I think there is some trick I am missing while initializing global variables. Maybe I need something like `flush`.

What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried reading only one file at a time, not reading all the files with a loop. *i.e.* not initializing the global variables again and again. I had no runtime errors.

A minimal example:

```
vector<int> **trucks;
vector<int> **presellers;
Customer *customers;
Customer *sortedCustomers;
double **distances;
int type, m, n, t, D, Q;
int id;
void readFromFile(const char *prefix, int instanceId)
{
    stringstream fileName;
    id = instanceId;
    fileName << prefix << instanceId << ".txt";
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName.str().c_str(), "r");
    fscanf(file, "%d %d %d %d\n", &type, &m, &n, &t);
    fscanf(file, "%d %d\n", &D, &Q);

    trucks = new vector<int> *[m];
    presellers = new vector<int> *[m];
    for (int i = 0; i<m; i++)
    {
        trucks[i] = new vector<int>[t];
        presellers[i] = new vector<int>[t];
    }
    customers = new Customer[n];
    sortedCustomers = new Customer[n];

    distances = new double*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        distances[i] = new double[n];

    int i, d, q, f, a;
    float x, y;
    fscanf(file, "%d %f %f %d %d %d %d\n", &i, &x, &y, &d, &q, &f, &a);
    createCustomer(i, x, y, d, q, f, a, t); // read depot
    for (int j = 1; j<n + 1; j++) // read customers
    {
        fscanf(file, "%d %f %f %d %d %d %d\n", &i, &x, &y, &d, &q, &f, &a);
        createCustomer(i, x, y, d, q, f, a, t);
        for (int k = 0; k<a; k++)
            fscanf(file, "%d ", &(customers[j].list[k]));
    }




    for (int j = 0; j<n-1; j++) // compute distance matrix
        for (int k = j + 1; k<n; k++)
            computeDistance(j, k);


}

int main()
{
    const char *inputPrefix = "t"; // prefix of the instance files.

    int begin = 1;
    int end = 42;

    for (int i = begin; i <= end; i++)
    {       
        readFromFile(inputPrefix, i); // read instance from file
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Inputs:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kdchj1g3e13aic8/files.zip?dl=0

Comment: Why these raw pointers actually? Sure you need them?

Comment: Just because you get a runtime error at a particular point doesn't mean that's where the bug is. You could have accidentally had any number of common bugs at any point prior to that, that ended up corrupting the heap; but the code execution continues, and only runs into the corrupted heap at this particular point, then crashes. Welcome to C++.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ those are arrays actually. and these need to be initialized after the problem is read from text file.

Comment: take away the `c` tag

Comment: @cagirici Please post a [MCVE] reproducing the problem, otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The code is a complete mess. There are hundreds of lines of code and three different header files. All are in use. Copying and pasting would not be helpful, I thought.

Comment: @cagirici I didn't ask you for copying the full code into your question, but for a ***minimal*** example that reproduces the problem. The code you posted doesn't.

Comment: Agreed make a small 20 or so line program that reproduces the error.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I tried to paste a code as minimal as possible.

Comment: @cagirici Why are you using those weird `fscanf()` statements in c++ code?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know the code is really really bad practice. This is how I am wanted to do it. It is not up to me, but the up to the project manager. As you can guess, the project manager is not familiar with software design. I am also not allowed to use `class`es etc.

Comment: @cagirici How does the project manager influence that you use `fscanf()` instead of proper c++ `std::istream` based methods? Weird hierarchy structure :-P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ a WHOLE different story. I had my life lesson: do not get involved into research projects as a coder IF you are not allowed to pick your own programming language and coding style.

Comment: @cagirici Well, `fscanf()` or not, you never check for any erroneous input or other error conditions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The files are properly formatted. If such input existed, the compiler must have given error when I run the program once for each file.

Comment: @cagirici No, the compiler doesn't care about runtime input. Check the return values of `fscanf()` statements for any failures or incorrect input formats.